# JqueryUI - Accordion. Display in one line

Tags: css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I use JqueryUI Accordion, and it works great.
I have a structure like this:

```
        <div id="accordionHolder">                 
            <div id="accordionOne"> </div>
            <div id="accordionTwo"> </div>
            <div id="accordionThree"> </div>
            <div id="accordionFour"> </div>
            <div id="accordionFive"> </div>
            <div id="accordionSix"> </div>
       </div>
```

This is displayed verticaly. Accordions are not big in size. How can I display  maybe two or three accordions in line?

Thing is this project is really big, and I am inserting a functionality. I do not dare to touch CSS (not an expert in any case). 
I have my page, a container in it. I can define my own rules there.

I have tried setting the main div to float-left and also display: inline... but without much success.

How can I accomplish this?

When I use: float-left on the accordions, they are not displayed anymore. Like they vanish. As soon as I remove the float-left, they show up again.

Image shows what I am trying to achieve:
[image]

I tried rendering accordion on separate divs, but when making it: Float-left, same things happens. It "enters" the previous one.
I tried moving them around with padding, but with lmited results. Probelm with this approach is when one accordion is expanded other move down, even if they are stacked horizontally.

I am runinng out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1):

The accordion divs accordionOne -> accordionSix should have css `display:inline-block;`
This will make them line up horizontally.